# Proper Way to implement Reusable Angular Reactive "Sub-Form"

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Hello I'm trying to understand which is the "best" way to implement a reusable reactive sub-form,

so far I understanded that a good way to do so is to implement `ControlValueAccessor` interface ([link](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor))

here an example I took from here [Building Reusable Forms in Angular](https://coryrylan.com/blog/building-reusable-forms-in-angular)

```
  import { Component, forwardRef, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
    import {
      ControlValueAccessor,
      NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      FormBuilder,
      FormGroup,
      Validators,
      FormControl,
      NG_VALIDATORS
    } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    
    // describes what the return value of the form control will look like
    export interface ProfileFormValues {
      firstName: string;
      lastName: string;
      email: number;
    }
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-profile-form',
      templateUrl: './profile-form.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./profile-form.component.scss'],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
          useExisting: forwardRef(() => ProfileFormComponent),
          multi: true
        },
        {
          provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
          useExisting: forwardRef(() => ProfileFormComponent),
          multi: true
        }
      ]
    })
    export class ProfileFormComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnDestroy {
      form: FormGroup;
      subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
    
      get value(): ProfileFormValues {
        return this.form.value;
      }
    
      set value(value: ProfileFormValues) {
        this.form.setValue(value);
        this.onChange(value);
        this.onTouched();
      }
    
      get emailControl() {
    return this.form.controls.email;
  }

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    // create the inner form
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: [],
      lastName: [],
      email: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.subscriptions.push(
      // any time the inner form changes update the parent of any change
      this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        this.onChange(value);
        this.onTouched();
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
  }

  onChange: any = () => {};
  onTouched: any = () => {};

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  writeValue(value) {
    if (value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    if (value === null) {
      this.form.reset();
    }
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  // communicate the inner form validation to the parent form
  validate(_: FormControl) {
    return this.form.valid ? null : { profile: { valid: false } };
  }
}
```

I then stumble in this article [The Best Way to build reactive sub-forms with Angular](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/angular-reactive-sub-forms-type-safe-without-duplication-dbd24225e1e8)

even though, in my opinion it seems a less "ergonomic" to do somthing like this to use the sub-form

```
@ViewChild(SubFormComponent, {static: true}) subform: SubformComponent

this.complexForm = this.fb.group({
//.....
subForm: this.subform.createGroup()
})
```

it makes some fair point, as of my understaing you should use `ControlValueAccessor` interface only when you have a single input which is complex in the view part

> All of these custom inputs, however complicated in their “view” part are only responsible for a single value like a rating or number of claps.
> Compare this with an address sub-form which works with a collection of stand alone values like street or city.

at the end of the article he makes some exemple of issues you could enconuter if you use `ControlValueAccessor` interface for "*multi filed sub-forms*", for example

> 1. manual propagation of the parent / child events
> 2. no easy way to show validation inside of the sub-form on parent form
>    submit event (we would have to track state ourselves by using
>    ngDoCheck life-cycle hook or similar)

**here my question**

**Can any provide some example of the aforementioned issues?**

Comment: Please check this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD_t3m2WMM8

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful! Anyway can you make an example of the two issues the author proposed? Even if in the video Kara Erikson proposed the CVA solution

Comment: @ALGDB, personally, I fully agree with the fisrt link, the CVA solution shoul be only to complex "view part" inputs. Even the first solution, pass as `@Input` a formGroup can be considered in a normal project (to has in the parent the definition of the FormGroup and in the children the "view" is no "so bad" against the simplex and robust). Imagine your parent get the data from an API, for me is natural create the form in the parent and pass as Input